# ¿Cómo puedo hacer la suma de las cifras de un número en java utilizando solo if y else?

Tags: java

estoy aprendiendo a programar y este es uno de los primeros ejercicios que hago. Me piden una función que devuelva la suma de las cifras de un número, por ejemplo, 125 => 1+2+5.
Ya hice mi función y sirve para números de dos cifras, pero después da fallos. Me ayudaría si alguien me dice en que me he equivocado, tengo que utilizar if y else, muchas gracias:

```
class Recursion{

 static double sumaCifras (double x){
       if ((x<10)&&(x>0)&&((int)x!=x))
         return (int)(x)+sumaCifras (x*10-((int)x)*10);
       else if ((x<10)&&(x>=0)&&((int)x==x))
         return x;
       else
         return sumaCifras(x/10);


 public static void main (String [] Args) {
    System.out.println (("La suma de las cifras de 1234 es ") +sumaCifras (1234)); 
}
}
```

La idea es que al introducir sumaCifras (número > 10), se divida el número entre 10 hasta que quede uno entre 0 y 10.

Entonces si el resultado de truncar este número "x" es igual al propio número (ejemplo: (int)7.0==7.0), se devuelva directamente el número "x".

En caso de que el número truncado no sea igual al propio número (ejemplo: (int)7.2!=7.2), se devuelve (int)7.2 + sumaCifras (7.2×10-((int)7.2×10)) = 7 + sumaCifras (72-70). Le he dado muchas vueltas y no entiendo donde está el fallo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si debugueas el código te darás cuenta que el problema se da debido a la falta de precisión al hacer operaciones con un `double`. La primera llamada al método `sumaCifras` lo hace con el número `1234.0`, la segunda con `123.4`, la tercera con `12.34`, la cuarta con `1.234`, la quinta con `2.34`, y la sexta al dividir el número debería hacer la llamada con `3.4` pero en realidad lo hace con `3.3999999999999986` y por eso te da un número mucho mayor al que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes una solucion elegante a mi parecer

```
public class SumaNumeros
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(sumaDeNumeros(123456789));
    }

    public static int sumaDeNumeros(int n){
        if (n <= 9) {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((n % 10) + sumaDeNumeros(n/10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código y en qué difiere o iguala al código del OP. Si bien puede ser la solución, de la forma en la que está redactada tu respuesta puede fomentar el uso de copy/paste lo cual podría no ser lo mejor para el aprendizaje.